# Importance of surface boundary conditions in a weather model

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, tropical-cyclone

I have a question regarding the usage of SST values for simulating a real time event such as a tropical cyclone.  I feel that I should use the most updated SST values in order to get the accurate intensity of my storm. But I also think that the updated SST can be cooler than the climatological ones and there are higher chances of convective inhibition within them. This also raises a question on coupled models as they are also used for operational forecasting.

Secondly, since the primitive equations corresponding to a regional weather model comprise an initial value problem I am unable to think of the extent to which the surface boundary conditions can effect the model solutions.

Comment: I am unable to discern a question here. What is the exact problem you are trying to solve  ?

Comment: @gansub I want to know about the sensitivity of weather models on surface boundary conditions such as SST. They might be important for a climatological case since the ocean responds too slowly, I am not sure if they are also important for the short time range.

Comment: You can calculate the SST anomaly and track the scale of the anomalies. If they are long lasting then you can ignore in the short range. If not then they need to be included.

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.839.3400&rep=rep1&type=pdf show the
sensitivity of the distribution of tropical convec-
tion  to  the  meridional  gradient  in  SST

Comment: Can you please edit your question to what you write in this comment?